# Curl POST Inserts Null Value to the table For Join Column

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jpa, curl, post

I have a rest api which runs on spring-boot. I am trying to insert data via post method by using curl command.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080/employees -d "{\"id\":\"5\",\"age\":\"40\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"salary\":\"300000\",\"surname\":\"Surname\",\"deptId\":\"2\"}"
```

Here is Employee entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
private Department department;
```

Here is Department entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "dept_id")
private Long deptId;

@Column(name = "dept_name")
private String deptName;
```

When I post data via curl, deptId is always null. I thought it's enough to give relational column but apparently it is not.

Comment: Employee does not have a property `deptId` so I am not sure how you would expect it to work. Try `{....."department": 2}`

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "dept_id")
private Long deptId;
```

Comment: They are different entities and placed in different classes for sure. But I wrote here together to ake it short

Comment: unfortunately it still inserts null

Comment: Employee and Department are different tables, different entities. But there is a relation between them, Employee table has dept_id column

Comment: I put the strategy, and it does not work. Still null

Comment: Thank you for the effort @Peter Šály